# Zero set of a multivariate polynomial over a general field

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, field-theory

When consider a multivairate (n variables) polynomial over field $\mathcal{R}$, denoted by $P(x_1,...x_n)$ , it holds that the zero set $\mathcal{Z}$ in real space is nowhere dense in $\mathcal{R}^n$,

where  $\mathcal{Z} = \{[x_1,...,x_n] \in \mathcal{R}^n|P(x_1,...x_n) = 0\}$.

Now I am wondering if there is any general statement regarding the nowhere denseness (or meager set) when considering zero set of $P(x_1,...x_n)$ over a general field $\mathcal{F}$.

In my case, I actually need to consider the field of rational functions.

Comment: Certainly not over a general field; e.g. $F$ could be finite. What kind of nowhere denseness or meagerness do you need?